# Low concordance index in logistic regression

Tags: sas, logistic-regression

I have been working on a project and I am stuck. I have used all the possible variables(relevant) for logistic regression, but the concordance index(c value) is not ready to go up(I'm getting 0.620). There is hardly any correlation between the predictors.

I am new to the statistical modelling, please help in summarizing the outcome.

Answer (score 0):

Address the questions:

- How do you determine relevant variables?
- Have you done preparation such as transformation of variables, filtering of 
  outlier ?

you could consider clustering before regression if variable k helps to predict the performance of a sub-group better than with the entire population.